# Lipschitz function implies gradient bounded

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lipschitz-functions

Let $f$ : $ \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Prove that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous if and only if there exists $M>0$ such that $\|\nabla f(x,y)\|$ $\leq$ $M$ for all $(x,y)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I'm trying to prove Lipschitz continuity implies bounded gradient but I don't even know where to start. I know that there is a constant $L\geq 0$ such that

$ |f(x_1,y_1) - f(x_2,y_2)|$ $\leq$ $L$$\|(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\|$

But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Can you try combining that with the definition of the gradient?

Comment: The gradient is a vector consisting of partial derivatives of $f$ at a given point? I still don't know how to proceed

Comment: Write down the limit definition of the partial derivatives and then use the definition of lipschitz continuity.